# confusion around Json/HTML, not sure varibles I and j?

Tags: html, json, variables, methods

This is a fragment of Json code:

```
myObj = {
  'name': 'John',
  'age': 30,
  'cars': [
    {'name': 'Ford', 'models': ['Fiesta', 'Focus', 'Mustang']},
    {'name': 'BMW', 'models': ['320', 'X3', 'X5']},
    {'name': 'Fiat', 'models': ['500', 'Panda']}
  ]
}

var myObj, i, j, x = '';

myObj = {
  'name': 'John',
  'age': 30,
  'cars': [
    {'name': 'Ford', 'models': ['Fiesta', 'Focus', 'Mustang']},
    {'name': 'BMW', 'models': ['320', 'X3', 'X5']},
    {'name': 'Fiat', 'models': ['500', 'Panda']}
  ]
};
for (i in myObj.cars) {
  x += '<h1>' + myObj.cars[i].name + '</h1>';
  for (j in myObj.cars[i].models) {
    x += myObj.cars[i].models[j] + '<br>';
  }
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
```

My main confusion is `for var myObj, i , j, x`, what is `i`, `j`, and `x`? is `i` just simply referring to `Ford`, and `j` referring to `BMW`?

Also for this part, `for (i in myObj.cars) {x += "<h1>" + myObj.cars[i].name + "</h1>";` What exactly will happen to `I`, just adding an new name, what is `h1`?

Comment: Sounds like you really need to do some research into the difference between JavaScript and HTML. Also, you have no JSON in your example code here; you have JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this is a javascript object, but you can still manipulate it. You might want to do some research on the key differences between JSON and javascript.

As for the first part of your question: `i, j, x` all refer to new variables, it would be the equivalent of saying

```
var i;
var j;
var x = "";
```

`x` is initialized using an empty string because it will contain a string later in the program.

The variable `i` is used as an index in `for (i in myObj.cars) {}` to keep track of each property of the object `myObj.cars`.

This would include:

```
0: {'name': 'Ford', 'models': ['Fiesta', 'Focus', 'Mustang']},
1: {'name': 'BMW', 'models': ['320', 'X3', 'X5']},
2: {'name': 'Fiat', 'models': ['500', 'Panda']}
```

Similarly, the variable `j` is used in the block `for (j in myObj.cars[i].models) {}` to refer to the different objects inside of `myObj.cars[i].models`.

For example, during the first iteration of the loop, `j` will equal 0, `i` will equal 0 and `myObj.cars[i].models[j]` will refer to this array: `[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ]`

As for the second part of your question `<h1>` is just an HTML header tag, and your program will customize the text inside of this header tag.

During this part of the program:

```
for (i in myObj.cars) {
  x += "<h1>" + myObj.cars[i].name + "</h1>";
```

`i` is set back to zero, and now it will loop through the entire list of objects inside of myObj.cars

In javascript, you can 're-initialize' variables, or better said, change their values dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

*i* is the index of your cars.

```
0: { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
1: { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
2: { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
```

*j* is the index of your models.

```
0: "Fiesta"
1: "Focus"
2: "Mustang"
```